# Using JColorChooser inside Processing 3.5

Tags: java, swing, processing

I'm trying to use a JColorChooser inside a sketch:

```java
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

color bgcolor = color(0,100,200,150);

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(bgcolor);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
}

void keyPressed() {
  bgcolor = pickColor(bgcolor);
  redraw();
}

color pickColor(int c) {
  Color javaColor = new Color(c, true);
  javaColor  = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Java Color Chooser", javaColor); 
  if (javaColor != null ) {  
    c = (int)alpha(c) << 24 | (javaColor.getRed() << 16 ) | (javaColor.getGreen() << 8 ) | (javaColor.getBlue() << 0 );
    println( "Picked:" + hex(c) );
    return c;
  }
  return color(0);
}
```

but Processing displays an error:

*The function "showDialog()" expects parameters like: "showDialog( Component, String, Color )"*

I also tried with `JColorChooser.showDialog( null,"Java Color Chooser",javaColor);` and with/without `noLoop()/loop()`, but the Dialog is not displayed.

> How can I fix it?
>   Is there a way to show a JDialog and/or JFrame in Processing ?

Comment: `JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Java Color Chooser", javaColor);` works just fine. I just copy-pasted your code into Processing, replaced `...` with `void setup() { noLoop(); colorPick(color(255,0,0)); }`, updated the showDialog line, and it runs without any complaints. Remember that Processing is based on _but does not follow the same scoping rules as_ Java, so outside of actual class methods there is no `this` that you should be relying on.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Which version of Processing and OS are you using?

Comment: The current Processing from https://processing.org/download/. OS is mostly irrelevant: Processing comes with the JVM bundled in, and so execution is purely based on that JVM, not the host OS.

Comment: I've updated your code to be a [mcve], with two tweaks: I've renamed `colorPick` to `pickColor` (a standard convention: name methods after what they do), and I've fixed how you're building `c` because `new Color(c)` loses the alpha channel entirely, so you'll have to carry over the original color int's `alpha(...)`. If you change `this` in your code to `null`, as you mention having already tried, that code runs perfectly fine in the current Processing.

Answer (score -1):

Finally creating a dummy frame seems to work, but I'll wait for other answers:

```
...
int colorPick( int c ) {
  Color javaColor = new Color( c, true);
  noLoop();  
  JFrame jf = new JFrame( "Dummy" );
  jf.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE );
  jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  jf.setAlwaysOnTop (true);
  jf.setVisible( true );
  javaColor  = JColorChooser.showDialog( jf,"Java Color Chooser",javaColor);
  jf.setVisible( false );
  loop();
  if (javaColor != null ) {  
    c = (javaColor.getAlpha() << 24 ) | (javaColor.getRed() << 16 ) | (javaColor.getGreen() << 8 ) | (javaColor.getBlue() << 0 );
    println( "Picked:" + hex(c) );
  }
  return c;
}
...
```